# Passing information between components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am currently trying to make a book store application, but I got stuck. How do I pass `book._id` as a prop to `EditBooks` components?

```js
{
   (edit && <EditBook editBook={editBook}></EditBook>)
}
```

```js
{
  books.map((book) => {

    return <div key={book._id}>
      <AiOutlineEdit onClick={(e) => {
        editBook();
      }}></AiOutlineEdit>
    </div>
  }
}
```

My `editBook` function displays a form to be filled by the user. Since it is a PUT request I need to pass the id to the `EditBook` component.

How can I pass the `book._id` when the React icon `AiOutlineEdit` is clicked to the component `EditBooks` for each book that exist in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want pass a data from a component to other component u should use code like this:

```
  const test=10;
  <Component1 key={key} data={test} />
```

in Component1:

```
   function Component1(props){
     return (
       <div>to show your data:{props.data}</div>
    )
    }
```

Comment: when a user clicks any one of the book I need to pass the book.id to the EditBooks component, how can I do this?

Comment: u need to make a component that show you list of your book that each row has button to show edit modal then in function of button by click on button you can send your book id to modal component and show data there