# Pass values from child to another child in react js

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass check box values to one child component to another child component, but parents are different and same grand parents using react js?

I pass value as props from one child component to parent component. But i think there is a correct solution for this. Please help

Comment: Have a read about React Context API.

Comment: use this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249703/passing-information-between-components-in-react/77249858#77249858

Answer (score 1):

Bad way: Pass the value to parent -> grandparent -> other parent -> destination.

Good way: Use state manager like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or [Context](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext)

Comment: I am a beginner in reactjs.  So can you please suggest some correct referring /learning sites and points.Thanks in Advance

Comment: try this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/redux-for-beginners/

Comment: Is Context hook is used for passing data from parent to child only?
Or we can use both cases means from parent to child and child to parent?

Comment: You can use Context to share either way, but in my opinion redux is better way ( cleaner, scalable )

Comment: Currently I am checking the data pass between components using Context based on your first component.
Okay.
Instead of Context ,I will check with redux now .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
How large is that data? If it's a simple string and there's no issue with storing it on the URL, use the query parameter as a single source of truth, but if it's a bit larger or you don't want to expose it to the URL, the React Context can be your answer.